# Kendo-UI bar chart display direction (axis)

Tags: kendo-ui, data-visualization

I am sure this is a stupid question, but I'm just not seeing it.

I have a page with many Kendo charts.  One of these appears where the bars go from left to right.  The others appear where the bars go from bottom to top.  What on earth is the property that controls this?  I simply don't see it.  I wan them all to be vertical in nature.

The single chart that is going from left to right is also the only chart that has its series predefined ([x,y,z] rather than using dataSource).  It also is the only stacked chart I have.  Maybe something there causes this?

Comment: can you share working code using jsfiddle?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The "bar" type sets the bars horizontal:

```
 $("#chart").kendoChart({
     seriesDefaults: {
         type: "bar"
     }
 });
```

And the "column" type sets the bars vertical:

```
  $("#chart").kendoChart({
     seriesDefaults: {
         type: "column"
     }
  });
```

Comment: Thank you. I had not ever seen this property. None of my charts were using it. Apparently with this omitted Kendo makes some internal choice of how to display these.  I figured it was something stupid I was doing!